# Javascript Function not returning document.getElementById value after each click

Tags: javascript, html, function, return, console.log

I have a script that populates several `.innerHTML` IDs through several clicks on a map. Currently, the `.innerHTML` show on the application as it should. My next step is to copy those same `.innerHTML` to a string. The string file will allow me to send the text information to the print job. I'm trying to create a function that would allow me to pass the `.innerHTML` to a string after every click on a map. However, the return on the function returns a blank or empty field. But when I do a console.log, it shows correctly. My question is how do I pass the inner.html to a string through a function? Any help is appreciated...

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.23/esri/css/esri.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.23/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css">


    <style>
      html,
      body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      #mapDiv {
        padding: 1px;
        border: solid 2px #444;
        -moz-border-radius: 4px;
        border-radius: 4px;
      }

      .shadow {
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
      }

      #map {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      #feedback {
        background: #fff;
        border: 2px solid #666;
        border-radius: 5px;
        bottom: 20px;
        color: #666;
        font-family: arial;
        height: auto;
        left: 20px;
        margin: 5px;
        padding: 10px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 300px;
        z-index: 40;
      }

      #feedback a {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
        color: #666;
        text-decoration: none;
      }

      #feedback a:hover,
      #feedback a:active,
      #feedback a:visited {
        border: none;
        color: #666;
        text-decoration: none;
      }

      #note {
        padding: 0 0 10px 0;
      }

      #info {
        padding: 10px 0 0 0;
      }

    </style>
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.23/"></script>
    <script>
      var map;
      require([
        "esri/map",
        "esri/Color", "esri/config",
        "dojo/_base/array", "dijit/registry",
        "esri/geometry/geometryEngine", "dojo/store/Memory", "dojo/dom-construct",
        "dijit/form/Button", "dojo/dom", "dojo/on",
        "dojo/parser", "dojo/domReady!"
      ], function(
        Map,
        Color, esriConfig,
        array, registry,
        geometryEngine, Memory, domConstruct,
        Button, dom, on,
        parser
      ) {
        parser.parse();

        map = new Map("mapDiv", {
          basemap: "topo",
          center: [-84.20, 33.78], // lon, lat
          zoom: 11
        });

        document.getElementById('countResult_H2').innerHTML = "Textx";

        map.on("click", getValues);

        var x;

        function getValues() {
          x = document.getElementById("countResult_H2").innerHTML;
        }

        var show = x;
        
        document.getElementById('countResult_x').innerHTML = show;


      });

    </script>
  </head>

  <body class="tundra">
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="design:'headline',gutters:false" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0;">
      <div id="mapDiv" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center'" style="overflow:hidden;">
      <div id="feedback">
          <div id="info">
            <div id="note">
              <br><strong>Info: </strong><span class="stats" id="countResult_H2"></span><br><br>
              <br><strong>Info2 </strong><span class="stats" id="countResult_x"></span><br><br>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you share more of your code so that the problem is reproducible? Otherwise, impossible to say

Comment: What are you expecting to happen when you click? The return value of an event listener isn't displayed anywhere.

Comment: If you want something to be done with the inner HTML when you click, `getValues()` needs to do that, not just return it.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
map.on("click", getValues);
```

will call `getValues` when the map is clicked, but the return value from that goes nowhere.

I think if you want a var outside of the function scope to be updated on clicking, you'd need to do

```
var x;
function getValues() {
  x = document.getElementById("countResult_H2").innerHTML;
}
```

That way `x` would be updated. However you'd then need something else to notice that x was changed, and do something with that.

### EDIT

As @Barmar points out in the comment, you need to do something *with* the changed variable.

Currently your code runs like this:

1. create a closure on the `x` variable.
2. set up click handler to update `x`
3. take a **copy** of `x`'s value, which is uninitialised, as `show`
4. set the innerHTML of `countResult_x` to the value of `show` (ie. empty!)

Then when you click, all that happens is that x changes. The rest of the code (steps 3 and 4) do not run because you have not told them to run.

It's unclear if/why you want a variable `x` scoped where you have it. It looks like you could just do it like:

```
    function getValues() {
      document.getElementById('countResult_x').innerHTML =
        document.getElementById("countResult_H2").innerHTML;
    }
```

Or you could do something like

```
var x = '';
function getValues() {
   x += "<br/><br/>x is now: " + document.getElementById("countResult_H2").innerHTML;
   document.getElementById('countResult_x').innerHTML = x;
}
```

Comment: I updated my post using your example. The problem is that "var show" does not get variable x and get passed to the next innerHTML.

Comment: I understand. I thought the map.on "click" would updated the x variable as the map was click on. Obviously, that is not happening. I need variable x passed because it will be used for another function not shown here.

Comment: you just need to make sure every function that is supposed to update something based on `x` is called whenever `x` is changed.

Answer (score -1):

just use 
 return String(x); for making value to string

Comment: Thanks but it did not work. I still receive a blank/empty string.

Comment: is your console.log(x);give any console output..??

Comment: Yes, the console.log(x) gives me the output I need.